# JQuery - returning value from .done function

Tags: jquery, return

I wonder how can I return value from .done function to the outer function which calls the .done function itself. For example,

```
var func1 = function(){
    var HowToGrabThis = func2().done(function(obj)
    {
        // some code
        return 'test'
    });
    alert (HowToGrabThis) // Should print 'test'
}
```

Comment: You can't. It's a callback. Put the `alert` inside the second `function`.

Comment: Alert is only for testing reasons. What I actually need is to return HowToGrabThis from func1

Comment: Again, you can't. It's impossible. Put the code that requires that information inside the second function.